# jQuery set radio button on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a radio button that I am trying to set with jQuery.

I know how to do this however I cant seem to get this one to work right.

My page has two sets of the same radio buttons on the page. The names are the same on both sets but the classes are different. (I know this is not how it should be done but I am just quickly testing something).

For the first set of input fields, this works just fine. It finds the input with the name of case and the value of 0 and checks it.

```
$(document).find('input[name="Case"][value="0"]').prop('checked', true);
```

I now am trying to set the same radio button in another set and cant seem to get it.

I am trying to say, find me the input field that has the class of `.esc` as well as the name `Case` with the value of `0` and set it for me.

Is there a way to look for an input with both a class and name in the selector?

```
$(document).find('.esc input[name="Case"][value="0"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: The selector should be `'input[name="Case"][value="0"].esc'`. What you have is a _descendant_ selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).find('input[name="Case"][value="0"].esc').prop('checked', true);
```